# Are any of these questions about attacks duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

The following question exists:

- [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245)

Currently, the following *are* duplicates of it:

- [Do saving throw based spells that do damage count as attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65415)
- [Can a Ranger uncanny dodge a blizzard?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144267)
- [Does an savethrow-type attack cause critical damage for an unconscious creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157340)
- [Does lightning bolt trigger wrath of the storm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142421)

Also currently, the following are *not* duplicates of it:

- [Is a spell with an attack roll "an attack" for the purpose of Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923)
- [Does the Ancestral Guardian barbarian's Ancestral Protectors feature grant resistance against spells such as fireball and toll the dead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136766)
- [Can a rogue use the Steady Aim optional class feature with attack spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180932)
- [Does the Ranger's Favoured Foe Ability from Tasha's work with Cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180666)
- [Would a Rogue's Uncanny Dodge feature halve the damage of a Magic Missile spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114451)
- [Can a familiar from the Find Familiar spell use Dragon's Breath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110157)
- [Can the Hexblade warlock's Armor of Hexes feature be used to cancel a ranged spell attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170820)

If those open questions are *not* duplicates, are the currently closed questions *also* not duplicates? If those closed questions *are* duplicates, are the currently open questions *also* duplicates? Which of these questions should and should not be marked as a duplicate of the general "What counts as an attack" question?

Answer (score 3):

From [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

> ### When are two questions considered duplicates?
>
> According to Stack Exchange co-founder Joel Spolsky, we should [only close real duplicates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), and according to co-founder Jeff Atwood, there are [three kinds of duplicates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/): cut-and-pastes, accidental duplicates, and borderline duplicates (requiring judgement as applied by the community).
>
> Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers**. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.
>
> Questions asking about the same aspect of the same concept, but with different examples, may or may not be considered duplicates. It depends how easy it is to figure out one example from the other. If it's only a matter of changing one small part of the question (e.g. in the case of coding sites, some numerical values or some variable names), they're duplicates. If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related.

So, using these criteria, a question is a duplicate if it is wholly answered by determining if something is or is not an attack. If the question includes issues about whether a feature applies to (some) attacks or not, or if it applies to things that aren't attacks then it is not a duplicate. For some of these, we are in borderline territory.

### Duplicates

These are all variations on "Is X an attack?"

- [Do saving throw based spells that do damage count as attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65415)
- [Can a Ranger uncanny dodge a blizzard?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144267)
- [Does an savethrow-type attack cause critical damage for an unconscious creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157340)
- [Does lightning bolt trigger wrath of the storm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142421)
- [Does the Ancestral Guardian barbarian's Ancestral Protectors feature grant resistance against spells such as fireball and toll the dead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136766) - This one could go the other way but I feel the bulk of the question is answered by "Is *Fireball* an attack?" rather than "Does *Ancestral Protectors* protect against non-attacks?" - the OP seems to understand that it doesn't.
- [Would a Rogue's Uncanny Dodge feature halve the damage of a Magic Missile spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114451) - A similar borderline case but the OP seems to know that if it isn't an attack then *Uncanny Dodge* doesn't apply.

### Not duplicates

- [Is a spell with an attack roll "an attack" for the purpose of Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923) - Whether the *Ray of Frost* is an attack (it is) is only part of the answer, the rest depends on if *Sneak Attack* can be applied to that attack (it can't).
- [Can a rogue use the Steady Aim optional class feature with attack spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180932) - Not a duplicate, like the *Sneak Attack* above, it requires an analysis of if *Steady Aim* applies to the attack rather than if it is an attack.
- [Does the Ranger's Favoured Foe Ability from Tasha's work with Cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180666) - Not a duplicate. Same reason.
- [Can a familiar from the Find Familiar spell use Dragon's Breath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110157) - Not a Duplicate. Same reason.
- [Can the Hexblade warlock's Armor of Hexes feature be used to cancel a ranged spell attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170820) - Not a Duplicate. Same reason.